# org mode inline image from elisp code block

Tags: org-mode, images, print

Below code will draw a tree graph with dot, it works fine but the output graph has been included in "".

```
#+NAME: nodes
| From | To | Weight |
|------+----+--------|
| A    | B  |      3 |
| A    | C  |      2 |
| B    | D  |      4 |
| B    | E  |      5 |
| C    | F  |     10 |

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output :wrap image :var nodes=nodes
    (defun rowfun(x)
      (format "%s -> %s [label=%s];" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x) (nth 2 x))
      )
    (defun dotgen(nodes)
      (let ((dotbegin "digraph {\nnode [shape=circle]\n")
            (dotend "\n}"))
        (concat dotbegin
                (mapconcat #'rowfun nodes "\n")
                dotend)))
    (setq dotname "test.dot")
  (setq pngname (format "%s.png"
                        (replace-regexp-in-string "\.dot" "" dotname)))
  (with-temp-file dotname (insert (dotgen nodes)))
  (shell-command-to-string (format "dot -Tpng %s -o %s" dotname pngname))
  (delete-file dotname)
  (print (format "[[./%s]]" pngname))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_image

"[[./test.png]]"
#+END_image
```

The output:

[image]

How can I get a clean image without the extra "" printed before and end of the picture?

Comment: What happens if you remove each double-quote from the second to the last line of your example code?  I.e., change `"[[./test.png]]"` to `[[./test.png]]`

Comment: it's from print output.

Comment: FWIW: one very kludgy solution I've used for this issue is printing a symbol since elisp allows most characters in symbol names (`(print (make-symbol "my-unquoted-string"))`).  Unfortunately that doesn't work for your circumstance with square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change (print (format "[[./%s]]" pngname)) to (princ (format "[[./%s]]" pngname))